# Using Xpra to Remotely Access an Ubuntu Unity desktop from Debian 11

Tags: debian, ubuntu, remote-desktop, unity, xpra

In the [Xpra documentation](https://github.com/Xpra-org/xpra/blob/master/docs/Usage/Start-Desktop.md), it says that you can remotely access a Linux desktop with a command like:

```
xpra start-desktop ssh://user@192.168.0.2 --start=fluxbox
```

How would you do this if [Ubunty Unity](https://ubuntuunity.org/) 22.04 is the remote desktop you're trying to access?

I have [xpra](https://xpra.org/) installed on both the client and the "server" (from the default repository), and I also have openssh-server installed on the Ubuntu Unity workstation:

```
sudo apt install xpra openssh-server
```

From Debian 11, I tried to access the Ubuntu Unity desktop like this:

```
xpra start-desktop ssh://user@192.168.0.2 --start=ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

And got this error:

[image]

> Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system
> can't recover. Please log out and try again. [ Log Out ]

Comment: Have you tried a different desktop environment? `ubuntu-unity-desktop` must be missing something..

Comment: @totaam : No, I haven't tried that because [Ubuntu Unity 22.04](https://ubuntuunity.org/) is the specific desktop I'm wanting to access remotely. The argument `--start=ubuntu-unity-desktop` was just a guess by me; I probably need to start something different, but I'm not sure what it would be.

Comment: I would start an `xterm` instead and run `ubuntu-unity-desktop` from there or from a separate terminal so you can see the details of the problem it's hitting.
Perhaps it is OpenGL related: https://github.com/Xpra-org/xpra/blob/master/docs/Usage/OpenGL.md

Comment: @totaam : `xterm` came up super small on my 4K monitor. When I typed `ubuntu-unity-desktop`, it said "command not found". I found this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/858729/256054), which caused me to try `sudo lightdm` instead of `ubuntu-unity-desktop`. Then it said `Failed to use bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager, do you have appropriate permissions?` From the client, I was able to get to a login screen with `ssh -X user@192.168.0.2 lightdm --test-mode` (not using xpra), but I couldn't type a password to login and I still haven't yet got in to the Unity Desktop.

Comment: you want to run a desktop environment, not a display manager. I don't think you should try to run a DM in xpra, they run as root and spawn sessions.